# GDB debugging tool for linux

Tags: linux, rhel-5, segmentation-fault, gdb

I'm executing a pro*c executable in linux and I've got segmentation fault error. But there is no core file dumped.

Thus, I want to debug the program using GDB debugging tool. However, I see that it is not installed on my Linux machine (a RHEL 5.3). How to install GDB debugging tool in linux? Do I need to download any package and install it, or does it come with RHEL?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: sudo apt-get install gdb

Comment: which distro???

Comment: Don't ask questions when the answer can be easily found via Google. And you did not specify what distribution of Linux you are using.

Comment: below is distribution details:                            Enterprise Linux Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Carthage)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga)
LSB Version:    :core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-ia32:graphics-3.1-noarch

Comment: @Hindol.. my question doesnt harm anything..

Comment: @Hindol you could have said this in a friendlier and more constructive manner. And we all know that sometimes Google has the proper answer buried under tons of crap :) There is no reason I see why this question cannot be answered without being harsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you don't have a core dumped on your disk is because often by default the core size is limited to 0 byte, thus core are not dumped.

To check this and correct it, simply perform this in your shell just before running your program (in the same shell):

```
ulimit -c
ulimit -c unlimited
```

The first command will give you the limit size for core files, the second one will make it unlimited.

Now you can run your program and it will dump a core upon segmentation fault. You still need GDB though.

GDB is an installable package that come with the Red Hat installation DVDs. Red Hat offers a nice and simple interface to do this, check [their online manual](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html-single/Deployment_Guide/index.html#ch-graphical-rpm). Search for GDB, selct it and click Apply. It will request to insert the installation DVD.